# Ubuntu installation is ignored

Tags: system-installation

I installed Windows 10 first.

Next, I installed Ubuntu 18 and chose "Install alongside Windows Boot Manager".

When I start my computer, it goes directly to Windows, not giving me any choice to start Ubuntu.

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

I just started reinstallation of Ubuntu to see that the current partitions on the single disk I have, as shown by the Ubuntu installation program, are:

```
Device         Type  Size   Used System
/dev/nvme0n1
 free space
 /dev/nvme0n1p1 ntfs 554    441 
 /dev/nvme0n1p2 efi  104    33       Windows Boot Manager
 /dev/nvme0n1p3      16     unknown
 /dev/nvme0n1p4 ntfs 397782 36471 
 /dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4 101646 9796     Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (18.04)
 free space          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out right after posting this. I had to change a "UEFI priority list" in my BIOS.